How can I create file filtering based on user input in WindowsFileSystemView` class in `javax.swing.filechooser?
I want to achieve the same functionality in WindowsFileSystemViewclass injavax.swing.filechooser that exists when the Open file dialog is opened from Word och Excel, i.e. when the user fills in a character in the filename input fields, then a list of the files in the directory that starts with that character is displayed in a dropdown under the filename input field. If two characters are filled in, the files starting with those two characters are displayed in the dropdown and so on.
I only know how to filter based on extensions, but don't know where to start if the filechooser shall filter based on input in the filename field.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I would like to know if there is a way to make the JFileChooser dialog show a dropdown under the Filename input field when the user types in one or more letters. For example, the user fills in the first letter in the filename to open "d", then the dropdown shows alls files starting with the letter "d" in the current folder. If the user types "di" then the list shall show all files starting with "di" etc etc.
